# Checking for existence of non-sequential list indices while assigning 'default' value

Tags: python, list

There is a list called `foo`. `foo` is expected to contain between 1 and 6 elements. If certain indices exist (specifically 1, 3, and 5) then the value of those indices should be populated into a dictionary `bar` with keys `x`, `y`, and `z`. If the index does not exist then those keys should instead be filled with `default`.

Just iterating over every index of the list and testing to see if i is equal to the necessary index isn't as simple as it sounds because the 'default' values need to be assigned for the indices which don't exist.

The initial approach was:

```
try:
    bar['x'] = foo[1]
except IndexError:
    bar['x'] = "default"
try:
    bar['y'] = foo[3]
except IndexError:
    bar['y'] = "default"
try:
    bar['z'] = foo[5]
except IndexError:
    bar['z'] = "default"
```

This feels quite ugly though. After all, if the first try block fails then there's no need to try the next two so we know they'll be out of range. I could nest the subsequent try blocks into the first but that hurts readability.

After considering the 'cleanest' way to handle this I've decided on this:

```
bar['x'] = 'default'
bar['y'] = 'default'
bar['z'] = 'default'

try:
    bar['x'] = foo[1]
    bar['y'] = foo[3]
    bar['z'] = foo[5]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

The logic here is that the dict will have all of the 'default' values assigned beforehand and then we can cover the list indices in order and if any of them don't exist then stop trying to assign the values and move on (because if index 1 doesn't exist then we know that 3 and 5 won't exist).

I have a nagging feeling that there are more optimal ways of doing this, though.

Is there a cleaner, more 'pythonic' way of handling this?

Comment: since you're dealing with constant indices *1, 3, and 5* - your 2nd approach is fine

Comment: [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: Is the problem that foo[1], or foo[2], or foo[3] may not exists?  You can use bar[key] = foo.setdefault(key, 'Default').  I assume it's foo since assigning for bar does not matter if the key exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion that might be a bit cleaner:

starting with the list `foo = ['a','b','c','d']`, we can define `baz = dict(zip(range(len(foo)),foo))`.

Using this dictionary, we can write expressions like

```
bar['x'] = baz.get(1,'default')
bar['y'] = baz.get(3,'default')
bar['z'] = baz.get(5,'default')
```